# How to put the result in variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem, I need to fetch data from DB and I want to put the result in a variable. Is it possible??

```
$dateNow = date('mm/dd/YYYY');
$getPendReq = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM master_tbl WHERE facility_id=2 AND status=2 AND dateSubmitted<'$GLOBALS'");
$getPendReq->execute();

while($row = $getPendReq->fetch()) {
    echo $row['requestor']."</br>";
} ;
```

My goal is to put the result in a variable `$list`..
any suggestion guys.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? `$list[] = $row['requestor']`

Comment: instead of echo $row['requestor'] . "</br>"; you can do $list [] = $row['myFielf'];

Comment: You can create an array variable. $list = array(); and store result in $list[]=$row['requestor']

Answer (score 1):

Make an array and push the results in it :

```
$list=array();
while($row=$getPendReq->fetch()){
     $list[] = $row['requestor'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sohrab Yousefi, after i put all the data in that array?? will I be able to print it without using while loop?? 

I'll be integrating the result in echo "";

Comment: It is an array. You can print it totally by print_r($list).
But if you want to access to each index of array, you must use foreach() like this:
foreach($list as $item){
echo $item;
}

Comment: Hi @Sohrab Yousefi, got it Bro.. one more thing, how can I concatenate 2 or more result from database. for Example $row['date'] & $row['requestor'] and so on.

Comment: Hi Bro. You can use character ' . ' to concatenate several variables or several results from database. like this :
$row['date'] . $row['requester']

Answer (score 0):

Just append Your data to an array.

```
$list = array();

$dateNow = date('mm/dd/YYYY');
$getPendReq = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM master_tbl WHERE facility_id=2 AND status=2 AND dateSubmitted<'$GLOBALS'");
$getPendReq->execute();

while($row=$getPendReq->fetch()){
    $list[] = $row['requestor'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$list[] = $row['yourresult'];
```